# nginx redirect non-www to www and https for domain.com and subdomain

Tags: nginx

Im having problems redirecting my non-www urls to www and https.

What I want:

```
http://domain.com 
http://www.domain.com
https://domain.com
```

should redirect to `https://www.domain.com`.

```
http://api.domain.com
```

should redirect to `https://api.domain.com`

I have seperata ssl keys for domain.com and api.domain.com. SSL settings for api.domain.com is handled via the node.js app. Furthermore domain.com uses a root document and api.domain.com is using proxy_pass to a node.js application on port 1336.

What I tried:

```
# route non ssl api to ssl
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.domain.com;
    return 301 https://api.domain.com;
}

# main ssl route for api.domain.com
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name api.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:1337;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

# route non ssl to www ssl
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.domain.com domain.com;
    return       301 https://www.domain.com;
}

# route non www ssl to ssl
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  domain.com;
    return       301 https://www.domain.com;
}

# main ssl route for domain.com
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

    server_name www.domain.com;

    location / {
        root /var/www/domain.com/www;
    }
}
```

Routes which are working as expected:
https://www.domain.com
http://domain.com
http://www.domain.com

Not working:

https://domain.com -> not secure connection, because it's trying to use the cert from api.domain.com (could this be cached, because maybe I tried it before another way, which was wrong)

https://api.domain.com-> redirects to https://domain.com

http://api.domain.com -> redirects to https://domain.com

> nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could get it working know. One problem was, that nginx route for

```
listen 443;
server_name www.domain.com;
```

was also triggering for https://domain.com. Also disabling the cache in the Chrome Dev Console for testing was a huge help.

Full config:

```
# main ssl route for www.domain.com
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.domain.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

    root /var/www/domain.com/www;
}

# non-www ssl route
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name domain.com;

    return 301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}

# route non ssl to www ssl
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.domain.com domain.com;
    return       301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}

# route non ssl api to ssl
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.domain.com;
    return 301 https://api.domain.com$request_uri;
}

# main ssl route for api.domain.com
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/privkey.pem;

    server_name api.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```